# multiple file uploader in reactjs form

Tags: reactjs, file-upload, redux

I have a list of items in database and I want to render it in table and will add input type=file for each to upload file for each item
on handle click i want to send item name to handle function but i couldn't,
to make it clearer i want send value item.documentname to file1MadChangedHandler function, every time i click

```
   {this.props.Organizations.listDocs 
    ? 
    <div>
       { this.props.Organizations.listDocs.map(function (item, index) {
          return(
                <tr key={item.documentName}>
                    {item.documentName}
                        <td>
                        <td>
                            <input component="input"
                                type="file"
                                id="{item.documentName}"
                                onChange={(event,item)=> { 
                                    this.file1MadChangedHandler(event,item) }}
                                // onChange={this.file1MadChangedHandler}
                                ref={fileInput => ref.fileInput = fileInput}
                                style={{ display: "None" }}
                            />
                            <button onClick={(item) => this.fileInput.click(item.documentName)}>Pick File</button>             
                        </td>
                </tr>
            )

        })
                }
    </div> 
    : 
    ""
}
```

Comment: Hi  Jayavel
When i click buttun i wanna upload file but my question when i click how to pass item.name to (file1MadChangedHandler) i want use the name came from database to upload the file, hope it's clear now

Comment: thanks for ur reply i tried but in file1MadChangedHandler(even,name)
i getting  name as undefined :(

Comment: hi @Jayavel
i have added my code to https://repl.it/repls/MutedFunnyBlog
can u check and i have 2 questions i hope u can help me

Comment: getting full path is not possible but we can have a temporary path.It's a security feature in all modern browsers.

Comment: ok, then how i can return result from upload function to item row ? to show it in <td></td>?

Comment: ok, appreciate your help and your time :)

Comment: thanks alot u really help me much i'm really sorry for disturb u second and last question and what i asked u yesterday , i added now here https://repl.it/repls/MutedFunnyBlog as i dont want distrub ur code, just i added button to refer to input  file uploader how to use it as im passing parameter, wish it's clear , sorry my english so bad

Comment: sorry dear Jayavel, just about last update it's not working fine plz try upload files from each row that what also i face yesterday

Comment: itsworking fine, great, appreciate your help and really thanks so much for ur time
u really help me much , many thanks

Comment: hi , i'm so sorry for disturb u just i wanna ask whether i can add u on skype :) thanks in advanced

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With inputs from your [repl.it/repls/MutedFunnyBlog](http://repl.it/repls/MutedFunnyBlog) code.

To get file name of uploaded item, you need to change your data slightly like below:

```
data: [
      { id: 1, name: "Copy of Applicant's Identification Card / Passport", "file": "" },
      { id: 2, name: "Copy of Business Registration Certificate (eg. SSM)", "file": "" },
      { id: 3, name: "Copy of Business Registration File 1", "file": "" },
      { id: 4, name: "Copy of Business Registration File 2", "file": "" }
    ]  //added file
```

then render each row like below:

```
   data.map((item, index) => {
    return(
      <tr key={`${this.state.inputkey}${item.id}`}>
        <td width="100">{item.id}</td>
        <td width="300">{item.name}</td>
        <td width="200">{item.file}</td> /* your third column */
        <td>
        <input 
          key={this.state.inputkey} /*unique key */
          type="file" 
          id={item.id} /*unique id cus every row should have unique input file type*/
          className="inputfile"
          onInput ={(e) => this.handleChange(e,item.id)} 
          data-name={item.id} />
        <label htmlFor ={item.id} > /* unique id for file upload*/
          <figure>
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="17" viewBox="0 0 20 17"><path d="M10 0l-5.2 4.9h3.3v5.1h3.8v-5.1h3.3l-5.2-4.9zm9.3 11.5l-3.2-2.1h-2l3.4 2.6h-3.5c-.1 0-.2.1-.2.1l-.8 2.3h-6l-.8-2.2c-.1-.1-.1-.2-.2-.2h-3.6l3.4-2.6h-2l-3.2 2.1c-.4.3-.7 1-.6 1.5l.6 3.1c.1.5.7.9 1.2.9h16.3c.6 0 1.1-.4 1.3-.9l.6-3.1c.1-.5-.2-1.2-.7-1.5z"/>
            </svg>
          </figure> 
        </label>           
        </td>
      </tr>
    );
});
```

and in handleChange event:

```
 handleChange(event, i) {
      const newData = this.state.data.map(item => ({...item}) ); //copy state.data to new data
      newData.map(item => item.file = i === item.id ? event.target.files[0].name: item.file);  //set file based on uploaded file in each row
      this.setState({ 
          data: newData, 
          inputkey: Math.random().toString(36) //set new unique key here
        }, () =>  console.log(this.state.data));
  }
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-nqfpfb) , Hope It clears your issues.

If you need to use button in the place of label, you have to make the button click event to trigger the input type="file" event.
[ButtonDemo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-essgsq?file=index.js)

```
<button onClick={e => this.enableInputFile(e, item.id)}>
    Upload
</button>
```

and

```
  enableInputFile(e, id) {
    document.getElementById(id).click();
  }
```

**note:You can't add for/htmlFor to button since it is not a labelable element check** [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label#attr-for).

Comment: Hello @Jayavel,
Can't we have Button in place of label ? If yes could you please help with same. Above works perfect.

It would be helpful if you can explain how its working fine now?

Comment: @DileepKumarKottakota If you need to use button in the place of label, you have to make few changes and the respective changes are updated in the answer. Please upvote it , if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

```html
fileHandler = (event) => {
  if(event.target.value !== ""){
    event.preventDefault();
    this.form.validateFields(event.target.name);

    const fileObject = event.target.id;  
    const name = event.target.files[0].name;
    const size = ((event.target.files[0].size)/1000000).toFixed(2);
    let img = [...this.state.img];

    img.push({inptid: fileObject,
      name: name,
      size: size});

    const fetchImage = img.map(e => e['inptid'])
    .map((e, i, final) => final.lastIndexOf(e) === i && i)
    .filter(e => img[e]).map(e => img[e]);

    this.setState({ img: fetchImage});

  }else{
    return false;
  }
}
```

**NOTE our render section and forms are comming dynamically via loop for your cases it might be different**

```js
<input
  type="file"
  className="form-control none"
  ref={formfields.title}
  name={formfields.title}
  id={formfields._id}
  key={formfields._id}
  index={formindex}
  onChange={this.fileHandler}
  required
/>

{
  img.filter(data => data.inptid === formfields._id)
  .map((data,index) =>{
    return(
      (data.inptid === formfields._id)
      ?
      <p>{data.name}   - <i><b>{data.size} MB </b></i></p>
      :
      ''
    )
  }) 
}
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, I feel that it might be necessary to include some context to it. Adding comment will increase it's long-term value.