# State value is undefined when pushing a new Object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to push an object `{link:href}` to the state in my project. When I try to add href in `{link:href}` it says it is undefined:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
class Download extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);

    this.inputRef = React.createRef();

    this.state = {
      files: []
    };
  }

  handleClick = () => {
    const node = this.inputRef.current;

    const self = this;

    let file;
    let name;
    let href;

    node.addEventListener("change", function() {
      const fileList = [];

      for (let x = 0, xlen = this.files.length; x < xlen; x++) {
        file = this.files[x];
        name = file.name;

        fileList.push({ name: name });
        let reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = e => {
          href = e.target.result;
        };

        fileList.push({ link: href });
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      }

      self.setState({ files: fileList });
      console.log(self.state);
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="input">
        <input
          onClick={this.handleClick}
          id="upload-file"
          className="inputName"
          type="file"
          multiple
          ref={this.inputRef}
        />
        <div>
          <ul ref={this.ulRef}>
            {this.state.files.map((file, index) => (
              <li key={index}>
                <Link to={file.link}>{file.name}</Link>
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Download;
```

The reason I'm trying to push `{link:href}` after the reader.onload function is because the reader.onload function gets loaded after the for loop runs x number of times and it only displays the last item.

Comment: By writing `reader.onload = e => { href = e.target.result; };`, you don't actually call that function, you're just editing it.

Comment: You don't need `ref` to get the files, React has a `onChange` event prop for input elements.

Comment: `.push` mutates the current state in place, see [how to update an array in the state](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26253351/1218980).

Comment: And here's [why you should not mutate the state](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37755997/1218980).

Comment: Also, it's useless to log the state just after setting it since the [`setState` function is async](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30782948/1218980).

Comment: Anywhere you're using `const self = this;` could be replaced with an arrow function.

Comment: And since you're already using an arrow function, `this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);` is useless in the constructor.

Comment: @EmileBergeron to resume, OP should just rebuild the entire component.

Comment: Also change `for (let x = 0, xlen = this.files.length; x < xlen; x++)` to `for (const file of this.files)` since he's not using `x`.

Comment: @EmileBergeron but I'm not adding to the state directly. I'm pushing to a separate array and adding that array to the state.

Comment: @DDavis25 Misread the code, my bad, you're right!

Comment: And the reason it is `undefined` is because `reader.onload` is an async function, so you're pushing to the array before `href = e.target.result;` actually runs.

Comment: @EmileBergeron I tried using an IIFE for the reader.onload function but it didn't change anything. What do you think I should do?

Comment: There are a couple of questions that already tackle file inputs with React. Like https://stackoverflow.com/q/55831213/1218980 or https://stackoverflow.com/q/54321502/1218980

Answer (score 0):

First thing, you don't need to use any `refs` for this. And you don't need to add an event listener to `node` (you don't need `node` at all) as you can use react's `onChange` instead of `onClick`. You also don't need to use a `Link` for this. You can just use an anchor tag with an href which you can assign the file data to. I prefer to use a function that handles downloads as I feel it gives me more control and doesn't affect your browser's windows or DOM elements. You essentially create an anchor tag, trigger a download and then remove it.

You are also pushing the elements in incorrectly. By pushing `{name: filename}` and then pushing in `{link: href}` you have just pushed two objects into your array and both of those will be mapped over. Instead, create an object, and add both of these key value pairs to that object and push that single object in. You don't need to push anything into the array until you reach the `reader.onload`. By pushing something in before the `reader.onload` and then again within the `reader.onload` you're just pushing something in twice.

Add the `name` to the object. Remove the first push and then in `reader.onload` add the `link` value to the same object and then push the object into the array. You also should not set the state outside of the `reader.onload` as this will trigger a re-render and render your incomplete object resulting in error. Only set the state once within the `reader.onload` so that when the re-render is triggered it will have the complete object in the list.

If you want your files to persist (meaning allowing multiple files to added to your file list) then rather than setting `fileList` to an empty array every time the `onChange` is triggered set it equal to `this.state.files.slice()`. We can use `slice` as to create a new array and not mutate `this.state.files` directly.

[Here is a working code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/wandering-lake-po9ng).

As you will see I also removed your `constructor` as for this use case just using `state = {...}` is sufficient. If you prefer to use the `constructor` you can add it back if you like, I just took it upon myself to save you a few lines of code.

```js
class Download extends React.Component {

  state = {
    files: []
  };

  handleClick = event => {
    let file, name, href;

    var breh = event.target;

    const fileList = this.state.files.slice();

    for (let x = 0, xlen = breh.files.length; x < xlen; x++) {
      file = breh.files[x];
      name = file.name;

      var obj = {};
      obj["name"] = name;

      let reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = e => {
        href = e.target.result;
        obj["link"] = href;
        fileList.push(obj);
        this.setState({ files: fileList });
      };

      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
  };

  download = (uri, name) => {
    var link = document.createElement("a");
    link.download = name;
    link.href = uri;
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    document.body.removeChild(link);
  };

  render() {
    console.log(this.state);
    return (
      <div className="input">
        <input
          onChange={this.handleClick}
          id="upload-file"
          className="inputName"
          type="file"
          multiple
        />
        <div>
          <ul>
            {this.state.files.map((file, index) => {
              return (
                <li
                  key={index}
                  onClick={() => {
                    this.download(file.link, file.name);
                  }}
                >
                  {file.name}
                </li>
              );
            })}
          </ul>
        </div>
        <output id="list" />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Download;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `fileList.push(obj);` mutates the current state since now it is initialized to `this.state.files`.

Comment: @EmileBergeron I added `slice` to create a new array from `this.state.files` without mutating the original state array.